# How to change the GitHub repository from which my repository was forked?

Tags: git, github

I forked a GitHub repository called masteruser/reponame to myuser/reponame. When I looked at its page it said:

myuser/reponame, forked from masteruser/reponame

Another user forked masteruser/reponame to anotheruser/reponame, and it said:

anotheruser/reponame, forked from masteruser/reponame

So far, so good. Then masteruser deleted masteruser/reponame by mistake. GitHub admins were kind enough to restore masteruser/reponame after a couple of emails from masteruser, but now myuser/reponame says:

myuser/reponame, forked from anotheruser/reponame

This is problematic, because now anotheruser/reponame is the default destination for pull requests, and it's not comfortable to change it every time I open one. I guess that I could just delete my fork and create a new one, but is there a cleaner way to do it? I couldn't find anything relevant in the repo admin screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest one of two options:

1. Delete your repo and re-fork the original one.
2. Contact Github fellows and explain your situation to them. They'll probably help you.

I couldn't find any option in the Github settings for this.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth, I contacted GitHub and they replied and suggested re-forking. It's really not a disaster, but I do hope that they'll make it more robust some day.